# Refresh from DB keeps OneToOneField Relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a simple model relation:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.OneToOneField(Bar)
```

Say I do the following:

```py
>>> bar = Bar.objects.create()
>>> foo = Foo.objects.create(bar=bar)
>>> Foo.objects.all().delete()
>>> bar.foo is None
False
```

This is expected because `bar` is still referencing the `foo` object. But now when I try to get a fresh copy of `bar` from the DB, i.e. without the related `foo`, I tried:

```py
>>> bar.refresh_from_db()
>>> bar.foo is None
False
```

Why does `foo` not come back as `None`? I see that in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) it says that only fields of the model are reloaded from the database when using `refresh_from_db()`. Does `foo` not count as a field of `bar` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Django version are you using?

Earlier versions of Django did not clear cache when relationship objects did not change it's id's. There is their ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29076.

It's already fixed in the new versions of Django.

Comment: Indeed, it is a problem with my version of Django! Thanks for pointing this out.